# Rotate camera relative to a point

Tags: c++, graphics, camera, glut

I need to rotate the camera around a player from a third person view. (Nothing fancy).

Here it is how I try it:

```
// Forward, right, and position define the plane - they have x,y,z components.

void rotate ( float angle, Vector interestPoint )
{
    Vector oldForward ( Forward );

    forward = forward * cos(angle) + right * sin(angle);    
    forward.Normalize();

    right = forward.CrossProduct ( up );
    right.Normalize();

    position = ( position + old_forward * position.Distance( interestPoint ) ) - (forward * position.Distance( interestPoint ) );

    this->angle += angle;
}
```

The problem is that if, let's say just do turn left a lot, the distance between the object and the camera increases.

Comment: It sounds like you need to add another parameter for distance of camera from object, or maybe distance and direction?

Answer (score 0):

For a very simple `orbit` camera, like most `3rd person` adventure games, you will need 4 things:

- The position of the target
- The distance from the target
- The azimuthal angle
- The polar angle

(If you want your camera to be always relative to the target in orientation, you need to provide the target's orientation as well, in this case I will simply use the world orientation)

See [Spherical coordinate systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) for a reference.

You should map your azimuthal angle on your horizontal control (and make it loop around when you reach `2 * PI`) and your polar angle should be mapped on your vertical control (or inverted if the player selects that option and make it clamped between `-PI` and `PI` - watch out for calculations based on the world `Up` vector if you go parallel to it (`-PI` or `PI`)

The distance can be fixed or driven by a spline, for this case we will assume a fixed distance.

So, to compute your position you start with `WorldForward`, which is a `unit vector` pointing in the axis that you generally consider to be your forward, for example `(1,0,0)` (here, if we were building a relative camera, we would use our target's forward vector) and you invert it (`* -1`) to go "from the target" "to your camera".

(The following is untested pseudo code, but you should get the gist - also, keep note that it can be simplified, I just went for clarity)

Next step is to `rotate` this vector using our azimuth angle, which is the horizontal orientation component of your camera. Something like:

```
Vector toCamera = WorldForward * -1;
Matrix horizontalRotation = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(azimuth); // assuming Z is up
Vector horizontalRotationPosition = horizontalRotation.Transform(toCamera);
```

At this point, you have a camera that can rotate horizontally around your target, now to add the other axis, you simply transform again using the polar angle rotation:

```
Matrix verticalRotation = Matrix.CreateRotationY(polar); // assuming Y is right
Vector finalRotatedVector = verticalRotation.Transform(horizontalRotationPosition);
```

Now, what we have is a `unit vector` that points to the position where the camera should be, if you multiply it by the `distance` you want to keep from your target and add the position of your target, you should get your final `position`. Keep in mind that this unit vector, if negated, represents the `forward` vector of your camera.

```
Vector cameraPosition = targetPosition + finalRotatedVector * distanceFromTarget;
```